# DynamoDb composite key with 2 columns

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamoDb table which has `conversation_id`, `token_id` and `timestamp` columns currently. `conversation_id` is partition key, `token_id` is sort key. Now combining `conversation_id` and `token_id` doesn't lead to unique row, so we are planning to add one more column `region`. Can I make `conversation_id` and `region` as partition key and leave `token_id` as sort key? Does it create secondary index on `region`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make conversation_id and region as partition key and leave token_id as sort key?

Yes if your concatenate `conversation_id` and `region` into a single string field.  Neither the Partition Key nor the Sort Key can span multiple "columns".  A table's Primary Key is made up of either one field (Partition Key only) or two fields (Partition Key + Sort Key).  DynamoDB calls the latter a [Composite Primary Key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/).

It's a common pattern to concatenate two or more attributes into a single string field, which is then used as a Key.  For instance, your Partition Key might take the form `region#<region-id>#convo#<convo-id>`, as in `region#ABC#convo#123`.    The use of prefixes and `#` as a separating character is arbitrary, but common practice.  It's just a string.  There's no reason `token_id` can't be your Sort Key.  It's common to use the generic key names `PK` and `SK` if you are concatenating multiple attributes into a single field.

N.B. The above example is just meant to demonstrate the concatenation pattern.  The question doesn't have enough information to actually recommend a key design.  [AWS says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach) ) key design should follow from your query pattern requirements (what questions need asking?) and data volumes/velocity.

> Does it create secondary index on region?

No.  Secondary indexes are explicitly created.  You can create a [secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) on region if you want.  A global secondary index creates another set of primary keys to query on.